# How to aligns strings inside jquery ui selecmenu

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, jquery-ui

I have a interesting question that dosen't find any answer: I have a group of string Companys names + ID inside a Jquery `Selectmenu` Widget:

Like:

- Company 1 - 00000023
- Company very large name - 00000028
- Another Company that have a very very very large name - 09900023

So we get this **Select menu**:

[image]

But I want to configure like this:

- Company 1                                                                           - 00000023
- Company very large name                                                  - 00000028
- Another Company that have a very very very large name - 09900023

**Final result:**

[image]

Here are my initial code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste alignment</title>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test Selectmenu</h1>

<select id="selectmenu">
    <option>Company 1 - 00000023</option>
    <option>Company very large name - 00000028</option>
    <option>Another Company that have a very very very large name - 09900023</option>
</select>

<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu( {width: 800});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to render the items in your own special way. Please review here: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ and check out the _renderItem section.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you will need to use `_renderItem`. Base on your description, there is a specific format to your String:

```
[item] - [id number]
```

The first thing to do would be to break up and wrap each part so we can style it with CSS.

```
function styleString(s){
  var result = "";
  parts = s.split(" - ");
  result += "<span class='item-title'>" + parts[0] + "</span> - <span class='item-id'>" + parts[1] + "</span>";
  return result;
}
```

Now we have to add this to our items.

```
$("#selectmenu").selectmenu({
  width: 800
}).selectmenu("instance")._renderItem(function(ul, item){
  var $li = $("<li>");
  var item = styleString(item.value);
  $li.append("<div>" + item + "</div>");
  return $li.appendTo(ul);
});
```

You can use `item.value` or `item.label`.

Now we just style the items.

```js
$(function() {
  function styleString(s) {
    var result = "";
    parts = s.split(" - ");
    result += "<span class='item-title'>" + parts[0] + "</span> - <span class='item-id'>" + parts[1] + "</span>";
    return result;
  }
  $("#selectmenu").selectmenu({
    width: 800,
    change: function(e, ui){
      $("#selectmenu-button .ui-selectmenu-text").html(styleString(ui.item.value));
    }
  }).selectmenu("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var $li = $("<li>");
    var item = styleString(item.value);
    $li.append("<div>" + item + "</div>");
    return $li.appendTo(ul);
  };

  $("#selectmenu-button .ui-selectmenu-text").html(styleString($("#selectmenu-button .ui-selectmenu-text").text()));
});
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu-text .item-id {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3em;
}

.ui-menu-item .item-id {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h1>Test Selectmenu</h1>
<select id="selectmenu">
    <option>Company 1 - 00000023</option>
    <option>Company very large name - 00000028</option>
    <option>Another Company that have a very very very large name - 09900023</option>
</select>
```

**Update**

Worked the same function on the proper element on opening and change. Added CSS for it as well. You had not mentioned the need for this in the selected item as well as the menu items.

Comment: Hello Twist and AA Norman, Thanks a lot!
But the inicial "closed" selectmenu was not formated.